# QGIS - “Error Entry Point Not Found” when launching QGIS 1.8

Tags: qgis

I am trying to download QGIS 1.8 on my windows operating system. When I tried to launch QGIS 1.8 a dialog box appears, preventing me from launching the software. This is the error that is generated:

[image]

I don’t know what this error message mean or how to fix it.

Comment: I suggest to install the latest QGIS version 2.8.2.

Comment: @AndreJ I want to use a plugin that's only compatible with QGIS 1.8. That's why i chose to download the older version.